# pass pointer to method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers, methods

Merry Christmas everybody :)

I have a pointer problem. Although I´m familiar with pointer concepts I haven´t used pointers in Objective-C so far the way it´s described here.

I modified it like this:

```
  int countSInteger = 10;

  [self setHMSValues:countSInteger];

- (void) setHMSValues: (int*) timeCat {
  *timeCat = *timeCat - 1;
}
```

But now I´receiving a EXC_BAD_ACCESS:
[image]

Any Santa hints?

### Greetings from Switzerland, Ronald Hofmann

Comment: May be, but I´ve been using pointers in other languages for more than 20 years and I have no problems there. My problem is clearly in Objective-C.

Comment: If you're going to declare the variable as an `int` and the parameter is an `int *` you need to pass `&countSInteger`.

Comment: This is not unique to Objective-C, you would have the same issue in C or C++.

Comment: @Cory: OK, you are right. But I started C/C++ and Objective-C just a short time ago. And there are also other languages besides C dialects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want `setHMSValues:` to calculate and return a value for the integer parameter. However, the parameter is a pointer to an int (`int *`), and you're passing a plain `int` with the value of `10`. Because pointers are just integer values themselves (with the integer value representing a memory address), the code is trying to set the value at memory location `10`; hence, you get a "bad access" error because your program cannot access or change values at memory location 10.

What you should do is pass the *address* of `countSInteger` to the method:

```
[self setHMSValues:&countSInteger];
```

However, there's a better way to do this. Since you're returning only one value from the method, there's no need for an out parameter. You can change your method to this:

```
- (int) setHMSValues: (int) timeCat {
  return timeCat - 1;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int countSInteger = 10;

countSInteger = [self setHMSValues:countSInteger];
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thanks a lot. As I said in my initial post this is simplified. Actually three parameters are passed to the selector. But return only returns one value.

Comment: I might point out that [Objective-C convention dictates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AccessorMethod.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH2-SW1) that an instance method that starts with "set" would be used as an accessor to set an instance variable. I would rename the method.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
- (void) setHMSValues: (int*) timeCat {
*timeCat = *timeCat - 1;
}
```

Comment: You're beautifying a bigger issue here. He is using pointers in a place where he has no need.

Comment: OK, before I used the int* thing I tried it without * but without success.

Comment: I modified my initial post because I´m receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using what you suggested.

Comment: Please please please use -=.  I hate seeing long form subtraction.

Comment: @CodaFi No need to hate numbers. But does that solve the problem?

Comment: @RonaldHoffman, I didn't say I hated subtraction, I said I hated the long form of subtraction.  In c, you can use a sign and an equals to take the value of the number and modify it by the value on the right.  In other words, he should have written *timeCount -= 1;

Comment: @FiCoda Well, I don´t hate it. And it is definitely clear than -=

Answer (score 1):

"`countInteger`" is declared as an "`int *`" while the method you're calling into is expecting an "`int`".

Don't you think you might have better luck if you declare "`countInteger`" as a plain "`int`"?

Answer (score 1):

Why use int pointers? Just remove the *

Comment: Maybe he wants an int out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Does Objective-C support pass by reference using & like C++?  I haven't checked Objective-C specifically, (never had the need) but in C++ the following is used to tell the compiler to use pass-by-reference:

```
void count(int &var);
```

Comment: As in C, there are no reference parameters in Objective-C.

Comment: That's a shame, and darn me for confusing C and C++ semantics... fixing... Fixed